# TinyMCE paragraph element unfocusable in Internet Explorer 11

Tags: html, tinymce, internet-explorer-11, tinymce-plugins, tinymce-3

I'm having a problem with Internet Explorer 11 not allowing an empty paragraph element to be focused in TinyMCE 3. I have a preceding paragraph element with various child nodes such as image and span elements that I have marked as non-editable with the core NonEditable TinyMCE plugin. They are inserted via the execCommand('mceInsertContent') function. Because of it being non-editable, I've had to insert a paragraph element immediately following the non-editable block and want the cursor to focus there which works. However, if I click into the non-editable elements after insertion, I am unable to then click back into the paragraph element below. It becomes completely non-focusable despite certainly being in the DOM since I can see it in the developer tools DOM explorer. I believe there is some set of interactions happening that's causing the following paragraph element to become unfocusable specifically after clicking into the non-editable elements.

I've tried every focus/selection manipulation I could think of and nothing worked. The only thing that seems to work (but is less than ideal) is to put a blank space in the paragraph following the non-editable paragraph. I'm not sure this is an acceptable solution though.

Here is the HTML I'm working with

```
<p class="mceNonEditable">
  <a href="www.google.com">
    <span>
      <img></img>
    </span>
    <span>
      Some Text
    </span>
  </a>
</p>
<p></p>  <---- can't focus into this element after clicking into preceding paragraph
```

Internet explorer seems to be the only browser I've ran into this issue with. Chrome and Safari allow focus on that paragraph element

Comment: Can't reproduce your problem on my side, it seems that everything works well on my side. You could refer to [this sample](https://codepen.io/davidemoro/pen/EVBmYy). If still not working, can you post the Enough code to reproduce the problem as in [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Thanks @ZhiLv-MSFT for looking at this. I spent some time messing around with the sample you provided but am having trouble getting my customization of TinyMCE working in that environment. For now, I've gone with the less-than-ideal solution of adding &nbsp; in that paragraph element in order to keep it focusable in IE. I think this issue is probably due to some combination of the various customizations done to the editor in the product I'm working with.